# How to wrap content of visible elements only in xamarin forms control

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a control in Xamarin Forms where I have a bunch of labels that are visible or invisible based on a few factors.

I want the layout I'm calling the control from to wrap the height based on the labels that are visible. So if the labels are 100dp tall for example (I don't actually know how tall they are) and there are 3 visible, I want the height of the control/layout to be 300dp. Right now the layout is just stretching out to what it would look like if all the labels were visible.

This is my control:

```
<controls:cardDetail>

  <Label Text="hi1" IsVisible="{Binding maybe1}">
  <Label Text="hi2" IsVisible="{Binding maybe2}">
  <Label Text="hi3" IsVisible="{Binding maybe3}">
  <Label Text="hi4" IsVisible="{Binding maybe4}">
  <Label Text="hi5" IsVisible="{Binding maybe5}">
  <Label Text="hi6" IsVisible="{Binding maybe6}">
</controls:cardDetail>
```

I call this control from a carousel view inside a stacklayout in another xaml page:

```
<StackLayout orientation="Horizontal">
  <CarouselView x:Name="carView">
    <controls:cardDetail/>
  </CarouselView>
</StackLayout>
```

What do I have to do to which page/layout to make this happen? Do I need to use C# or can I just add an attribute in xaml??

Thanks!

Comment: I confused about you achievement, above code have a issue, you cannot put the `controls:cardDetail` to `CarouselView` directly. You should put it in the `CarouselView`'s `DataTemplate`.  What is your type of `cardDetail`? Is it a `ContentView`?

Comment: Sorry I didn't think that part was important but yeah the control is inside a DataTemplate. And it's just based off a StackLayout with some added properties @LeonLu-MSFT

Comment: Can you share your code about `controls:cardDetail`? If the type of `cardDetail` is `ContentView`, `Label` could be added, and this control could be added in the `CarouselView`'s `DataTemplate`.